# General question on how StateUpdates work with Riverpod

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Let's say I provide Data to a Consumer via the watch(provider) method. And depending on the Data the Consumer returns a statefulWidget. If I'd call setState() on the StatefulWidget, would the state of the consumer refresh and therefore call watch(provider) again?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the watch() is inside the build() method.  If so, it might be called 60 times per second, and thus the watch will be called likewise.

Comment: but still if something changes in that widget the changes won't be displayed